Loading a CSV into mariadb errs out as "invalid date format"
I am trying to load CSV into a MariaDB .
Having issues in transforming date .
Here is an example file and two tables
( emp , where dob is declared as a date column and emp_varchar , where dob is declared
as varchar).
What am I doing wrong here?
Jane@dbserver1:~$ cat empdata.csv
100,John ,02/14/1955
200,Jane ,08/22/1980


MariaDB [emptest]>  LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'empdata.csv'
    ->     INTO TABLE   emp
    ->     FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    ->     OPTIONALLY  ENCLOSED BY '\"'
    ->     LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    ->     IGNORE 0 ROWS
    ->     (
    ->                 eid,
    ->                 ename,
    ->                 dob
    ->  )
    ->      SET dob =  STR_TO_DATE(dob, '%m/%d/%Y');
Query OK, 2 rows affected, 4 warnings (0.001 sec)
Records: 2  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 4

MariaDB [emptest]>             show warnings;
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                         |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'dob' at row 1                        |
| Warning | 1411 | Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00' for function str_to_date |
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'dob' at row 2                        |
| Warning | 1411 | Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00' for function str_to_date |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [emptest]> select * from emp;
+------+-----------+------+
| eid  | ename     | dob  |
+------+-----------+------+
|  100 | John      | NULL |
|  200 | Jane      | NULL |
+------+-----------+------+
2 rows in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [emptest]>  LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'empdata.csv'
    ->     INTO TABLE   emp_varchar
    ->     FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    ->     OPTIONALLY  ENCLOSED BY '\"'
    ->     LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    ->     IGNORE 0 ROWS
    ->     (
    ->                 eid,
    ->                 ename,
    ->                 dob
    ->  )
    ->      SET dob =  STR_TO_DATE(dob, '%m/%d/%Y');
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.001 sec)
Records: 2  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [emptest]> select * from  emp_varchar
    -> ;
+------+-----------+------------+
| eid  | ename     | dob        |
+------+-----------+------------+
|  100 | John      | 1955-02-14 |
|  200 | Jane      | 1980-08-22 |
+------+-----------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [emptest]>


This question is similar to: Import multiple CSV fields into one MySQL field. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

From LOAD DATA INFILE

In the case of a variable, the SET statement can be used to preprocess
the value before loading into the table.

If no variable is used during the LOAD DATA process, first the data is loaded into the table and then applies the SET clause.
Use,
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/empdata.csv'
INTO TABLE   emp
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY  ENCLOSED BY '\"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 0 ROWS
(eid, ename, @dob) 
SET dob = STR_TO_DATE(@dob, '%m/%d/%Y');


Tested on 10.6.15-MariaDB
MariaDB [crm_gesti]> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/empdata.csv'
    -> INTO TABLE   emp
    -> FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    -> OPTIONALLY  ENCLOSED BY '\"'
    -> LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    -> IGNORE 0 ROWS
    -> (eid, ename, @dob)
    -> SET dob = STR_TO_DATE(@dob, '%m/%d/%Y');
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.001 sec)
Records: 2  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [crm_gesti]> select * from emp;
+------+-------+------------+
| eid  | ename | dob        |
+------+-------+------------+
|  100 | John  | 1955-02-14 |
|  200 | Jane  | 1980-08-22 |
+------+-------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [crm_gesti]> show create table emp;

CREATE TABLE `emp` (
  `eid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ename` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dob` date DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci 

